# How can I add a function to each option in my form? (HTML, JS)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```
<div class="form-group mycustom-form-group mt-3">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">What would you like to do:</label>
<form action="" method="POST" id="form1" onclick="mySubmit()">
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" >
  <option value="1">Image Rollover</option> 
  <option value="2">Image Preview</option>
  <option value="3">Image Slideshow</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value = "Submit">
```

In my form when I select an option and submit, I would each option to allow me to do what the option entails,(open an image, create a document.write(),make an image rollover, etc). How can I create a function in each option when I select it and submit? (If my question requires more clarification, please let me know)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `onchange` event in select and do whatever you want to do on change of value.

```
<div class="form-group mycustom-form-group mt-3">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">What would you like to do:</label>
<form action="" method="POST" id="form1" onclick="mySubmit()">
<select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" onchange="yourFunction()">
  <option value="1">Image Rollover</option> 
  <option value="2">Image Preview</option>
  <option value="3">Image Slideshow</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value = "Submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `onchange` event in select and create a function to handle it.

```
<div class="form-group mycustom-form-group mt-3">
<label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">What would you like to do:</label>
<form action="" method="POST" id="form1" onclick="mySubmit()">
<select class="form-control" onchange="handleSelectChange()" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" >
  <option value="1">Image Rollover</option> 
  <option value="2">Image Preview</option>
  <option value="3">Image Slideshow</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value = "Submit">
```

You can refer to the document here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Do you know how I can have it do my function after I hit submit? Not just select the option, but select the option and submit